Dashed Rectangle in CircuiTikZ
I am trying to draw the following circuit:

I've been working on it and this is my result:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
        (0,0) to[short, *-] ++(1,0) coordinate(A) to[R=\(R_{1}\)] ++(2,0) coordinate(B) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(C) -- ++(1,0)
        node[op amp, noinv input down, anchor=-, fill=cyan!20](OA1){\texttt{OA1}}
        (A) -- ++(0,1.25) to[C=\(C_{1}\)] ++(2,0) -- (B)
        (C) -- ++(0,1.25) to[R=\(R_{2}\)] ++(2,0) to[C=\(C_{2}\)] ++(1.38,0) -- (OA1.out)
        (OA1.out) to[R=\(R_{3}\)] ++(2,0) coordinate(D) -- ++(1,0)
        node[op amp, noinv input down, anchor=-, fill=cyan!20](OA2){\texttt{OA2}}
        (D) -- ++(0,1.25) coordinate(tmp) to[R=\(R_{4}\)] (OA2.out|-tmp) -- (OA2.out)
        (OA2.out) to[short, -*] ++(1,0)
        (OA2.+) -| ++(-1,-1) to[short, -*] ++(4.38,0)
        (OA1.+) -| ++(-1,-1.49) coordinate(E) -- ++(3.38,0) coordinate(F) -- ++(2,0)
        (E) to[short, -*] ++(-4,0)
        (F) node[ground]{} ++(0,-1)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


What I am trying to figure out is, how to draw the dashed rectangles. I have read the CircuiTikZ manual, and understand the rough idea of what I have to do, but I am stuck in applying it to my circuit. Also, how to put the node of E's here? I, too, am open to a better way to do what I have coded so far (if there's any)!

It would be best if you learned to use orthogonal coordinates; they are fundamental to having nice circuits... also calculated ones are handy (the calc library is automatically loaded by circuitikz)
Anyway, with explanations in comments:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
        %% add names to the things you need to box and to the voltage coord
        (0,0) coordinate(in)
        to[short, *-] ++(1,0) coordinate(A) to[R=\(R_{1}\), name=r1] ++(2,0)
        coordinate(B) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(C) -- ++(1,0)
        node[op amp, noinv input down, anchor=-, fill=cyan!20](OA1){\texttt{OA1}}
        (A) -- ++(0,1.25) to[C=\(C_{1}\), name=c1] ++(2,0) -- (B)
        (C) -- ++(0,1.25) to[R=\(R_{2}\), name=r2] ++(2,0)
        %% do not do this! see below, I fixed one
        to[C=\(C_{2}\), name=c2] ++(1.38,0) -- (OA1.out)
        (OA1.out) to[R=\(R_{3}\)] ++(2,0) coordinate(D) -- ++(1,0)
        node[op amp, noinv input down, anchor=-, fill=cyan!20](OA2){\texttt{OA2}}
        (D) -- ++(0,1.25) coordinate(tmp) to[R=\(R_{4}\)] (OA2.out|-tmp) -- (OA2.out)
        (OA2.out) to[short, -*] ++(1,0) coordinate(out)
        %% DO NOT DO THIS --- adjusting numbers like that
        %% (OA2.+) -| ++(-1,-1) to[short, -*] ++(4.38,0)
        %% use orthogonal coordinates!!!
        (OA2.+) -| ++(-1,-1) coordinate(low) to[short, -*] (low-|out)
        %% fix this also
        (OA1.+) -| ++(-1,-1.49) coordinate(E) -- ++(3.38,0) coordinate(F) -- ++(2,0)
        (E) to[short, -*] ++(-4,0) coordinate(in down)
        (F) node[ground]{} ++(0,-1)
        ;
    %% now create  "fit"-ed nodes for the blocks
    %% notes that the name `c1label` is added by cicuitikz, see section 5.7
    %% manually adjust inner xsep and/or inner ysep to your taste
    \node [draw, blue, dashed, fit=(r1) (c1label), inner xsep=18pt] (Z1){};
    \node [draw, blue, dashed, fit=(r2) (c2label) (c2)] (Z2){};
    %% add labels to the blocks
    \node [above] at (Z1.north) {$Z_1(s)$};
    \node [above] at (Z2.north) {$Z_2(s)$};
    %% add the voltage labels to various points
    %% BUT NOTICE, I would add the signs too... as you wrote your example,
    %% you are assuming that the negative side of the voltage is ground
    %% put the label midway between (in) and (in down), similar for the other
    \node at ($(in)!0.5!(in down)$) {$E_i(s)$};
    \node at ($(OA1.out)!0.5!(F)$) {$E(s)$};
    \node at ($(out)!0.5!(low-|out)$) {$E_o(s)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Hi again! Wow, you helped me a lot. Your explanation has enlightened me! What I've been wondering about the rectangle is how do I tell LaTeX that I want to create a rectangle with these coordinates but with an outer padding? And, thanks to you, now it's answered! :-)

You really should check out the TikZ manual.  Circuitikz is TikZ with some additional definitions.

@JohnKormylo That makes sense. I only checked the CircuiTikZ manual. Thank you for suggesting!
